# How to get all possible combinations of elements in a given list?

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop, recursion, permutation

Let's say we have a list: `['a','b','c','d']`
The output must be:

```
abcd
abdc
acbd
acdb
adbc
adcb
bacd
badc
bcad
bcda
bdac
bdca
cabd
cadb
cbad
.....
```

and so on.

I can make the program if I knew the number of elements in the list,
but the list is given by the user (consider that the user gives a list of unique elements).

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
for h in l: 
    for i in l:
        ll = [h+i+j+k for j in l for k in l if len([h,i,j,k])==len(set([h,i,j,k]))] 
        for m in ll:
            print(m)
```

This program gave me the above output.

If I wanted for 3 elements I could remove a `for` loop or if I wanted for 5 elements I could add a `for` loop,
but the program has to consider the number of elements at runtime and give output.
Basically I am looking for a generalized algorithm that can handle any number of elements.

I think recursion is the way but don't know how to do it.
Also tried to do it without *itertools* permutation method.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Every permutation a) starts with one element of the list and b) ends with a permutation of what remains.  Sounds like a recursive recipe to me.

Comment: @ScottHunter What remains if `n` exceeds the length of `l`? What should happen in that case @monarch?

Comment: @JonSG: What is `n`?  There is no `n` in either the post or my comment.

Comment: @JonSG: "try to do it without itertools' permutation method"

Comment: Sorry, `n` is the number of "loops" where the op is asking about *"If I wanted for 3 elems i cud remove a for loop or if i wanted for 5 elems i cud add add a for loop."* so list of length 4 with potential `n`s of 3 or 5 I guess.

Comment: @ScottHunter Sorry I read that as "try to" not "don't try to"...

Comment: @JonSG: Every permutation a) starts with one element of the list and b) ends with a 1 element shorter permutation of what remains. (assumes the length of your desired permutations are no longer than your list of elements).

Comment: Yes, I understand that in the case that the OP wanted results of the same length as the original list. I was under the impression that the OP was looking for results of lengths larger than the original list. for example one of the items in the results potentially being `["a","b","d","c", "a"]` ie items of length 5 when the input was length only length 4. If that is not what it mean by "for 5 elements" then sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recursive version:

```
def combinations(items):
    if len(items) <= 1:
        return [items]
    combs = []
    for i, item in enumerate(items):
        others = items.copy()
        others.pop(i)
        for sub_comb in combinations(others):
            whole = [item]
            whole.extend(sub_comb)
            combs.append(whole)
    return combs

elems = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
all_combs = combinations(elems)
for comb in all_combs:
    print(''.join(comb))
```

It outputs 6 combinations for 3 elements, 24 for 4, 120 for 5, and so on.

This is *n!* (factorial), which is the exact number of [permutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) that *n* distinct elements can produce.

Comment: i just completed my own version of this program which was similar to your answer. But your program is better considering readability and understanding. Anyway Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using [dfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search):

```py
def perms(string, current="", visited=None):
    if visited is None:
        visited = [False] * len(string)

    if len(current) == len(string):
        yield current
    else:
        for i in range(len(string)):
            if not visited[i]:
                visited[i] = True
                yield from perms(string, current + string[i], visited)
                visited[i] = False
```

Note that this will return a generator expression, so you can output with something like this:

```py
for perm in perms("".join(["a", "b", "c", "d"])):
    print(perm)
```

Answer (score -1):

@hedfol's solution as a generator:

```
def combinations(src,prefix=[]):
    if len(src) == 1:
        yield prefix+src
    else:
        for i,x in enumerate(src):
            for y in myperm(src[:i]+src[i+1:], prefix+[x]):
                yield y
```